ADS7828: Should I connect REFIN/OUT to 5V when using a 5V analog sensor output?
I'm planning to use the ADS7828 ADC from Texas Instruments because it supports I2C communication and meets my desired sample rate. My analog sensor operates at 5V and outputs values between 0.5V and 4.5V, so I need the ADC to measure this range accurately.
Here’s my setup so far:

VDD (power supply) of the ADS7828 is connected to 5V.
The sensor’s analog output is connected to one of the ADS7828 channels (e.g., CH0).

The confusion comes from the REFIN/REFOUT pin (Pin 10):
From the datasheet, the internal reference is 2.5V.
However, I want to measure a 0.5V–4.5V range, so I assume I need to provide 5V as an external reference to REFIN.
My question is:
Should I connect REFIN to 5V to achieve full dynamic range (0V–5V)?
Or should I leave REFIN floating/grounded and rely on the internal 2.5V reference?
I’m stuck because the Datasheet seems to suggest the internal reference remains at 2.5V even when powered by 5V VDD (Values Table on the Datasheet at Vdd 5V). I’m unsure whether forcing 5V on REFIN is correct or if this causes issues.

It depends on your sensor. If your sensor provides a ratiometric output then it will be better to use the 5V as the reference, since the sensor output will vary proportionally with the supply voltage, so the variation will largely cancel out if the supply voltage is used as a reference. That's a typical situation with 0.5 to 4.5V output sensors. If you provide a stable reference to the ADC with a ratiometric sensor you'll also be measuring the difference between the two references. Of course you need an electrically 'clean' and relatively stable 5V even so for best results- using a supply with a lot of high-frequency noise on it can lead to sub-optimal results.
Otherwise (if the sensor is not ratiometric) your best bet is probably to use the internal 2.5V reference and divide down the sensor output. Or use an external 4.096V reference if the slight loss of range at the high end is not an issue.
